# Only one expectation per it {} block: So how to improve this spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

My Rails models: task has_many positions.

Scenario: When I create a new position, it should create itself a task. I'd like to test that, and I'm doing it like this:

```
context "creating a new position" do
  let(:position) { create :position, name: 'Read some books', :task => nil }

  it "should create a simple task" do
    Task.find_by_name('Read some books').should be_nil # First should
    position # Execute let() block (FactoryGirl is lazy evaluating)
    Task.find_by_name('Read some books').should_not be_nil # Second (more relevant) should
  end
end
```

So how should I improve my test? The first "should" simply makes sure that there isn't already a Task, so we can be sure that creating the Position creates the Task. But this violates the "only one should per it block" principle. So what about this?

```
context "creating a new position" do
  let(:position) do
    position = create :position, name: 'Read some books', :task => nil
    Task.delete_all
    position
  end

  it "should create a simple task" do
    position # Execute let() block (FactoryGirl is lazy evaluating)
    Task.find_by_name('Read some books').should_not be_nil
  end
end
```

Or should I simply count on the fact that there shouldn't be such a task anyways (because a clean test db wouldn't have one)? Thanks for your opinions.

**Update (Solution)**

After some research I found the `change` matcher of RSpec:

```
let(:position) { create :position, name: 'Read some books', :task => nil }

it "should create a simple task" do
  # Thanks to FactoryGirl's lazy evaluation of let(), the position doesn't yet exist in the first place, and then after calling position in the expect{} block, it is created.
  expect { position }.to change{ Task.count(conditions: { name: 'Read some books' }) }.by(1)
end
```

Comment: Create a task with an arbitrary, generated name. Ensure there's a new task and its name is the generated name.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like arbitrary names too much. I found a bettersolution, see my Update above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RSpec 2.11](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-11/docs/built-in-matchers/expect-change) allows you to pass a block to `change`, and it expects the return value of the block to be the thing that changes. I would expect this to work for you:

```
expect { position }.to change { Task.where(:name => 'Read some books').count }.from(0).to(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I found it out myself right before you added your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

#### What to Test

I will not address in detail whether the tests themselves are useful to any degree. To me, they seem to be exercising basic database functions rather than application logic, which is of marginal utility, but only you can really decide what's important to test.

#### Be Specific

In the example you give, there's no real reason to use a let block, which memoizes the variable. If only one test needs the record, instantiate it just in that specific test. For example:

```
context 'creating a new position' do
  it 'should be nil when the position record is missing' do
    Task.find_by_name('Read some books').should be_nil
  end

  it 'should successfully create a position' do
    create :position, name: 'Read some books', :task => nil
    Task.find_by_name('Read some books').should_not be_nil
  end
end
```

Alternatively, if you're trying to test how your application behaves when a record is missing, then go ahead and memoize a variable or create a record in a before block, but explicitly delete the record *in that one specific test*.

#### Multiple Contexts

Finally, if you're finding that you have too much state to set up in individual tests, that's usually a clue that you should consider splitting your tests into different contexts. For example, you might want to separate tests into one context that checks behavior when a record doesn't exist, and a separate context for when records *do* exist.

Like all things testing, it's an art more than a science. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: It's true, it really is an art, and I'm just diving right into it since some weeks. But I think you don't really understand what I'm testing, I'm testing a before_save filter which automatically creates a Task for a new Position, so this definitely isn't just basic db functions. Anyways, I solved my problem, and I'm also thankful for your comment. :)